# Framework7: How to refresh a page after changing template data?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, html-framework-7

The document says, we can change the template data. But after modifying the data, the page content is not updated. I don't understand what is the meaning if the updated data cannot be presented.

Can anybody tell me how to refresh the data?

Thanks.

Comment: can you able to tell how you tried>

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how you had compiled the template

if you are using a template like

```
<script id="template1" type="text/template7">....</script>
```

thin to compile and load the page you can manually compile and load by doing

```
var compiledTemplate = Template7.compile(template);
var data = {
    foo: 'bar'
};
var html = compiledTemplate(data);
$$('#element').html(html);
```

---

if your are using a template page 
Ex: **home_page.html**

```
<div class="pages navbar-through">
<div data-page="home" class="page navbar-through">
    ....
    <div>{{foo}}<div>
    ...
```

then you can autocompile the page using `Framework7`

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    ...
    precompileTemplates: true,
    template7Pages: true,
    template7Data: {
        'url:pages/home_page.html': {foo: 'bar'}
    }
});
```

---

**Note**
you can't compile your default page Ex: page in `index.html` but if you want to do that move the content of that page to another file ex `main_page.html` and use

```
mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
        dynamicNavbar: true // for ios only
    });
mainView.router.loadPage('pages/main_page.html');
```

for more info read [Template7 syntax](http://www.idangero.us/template7/#.Vn1-YZN95Xh)

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome press F12 to go to developer mode then hold the reload button before the address bar for more than 1 second. This action will reveal you the `Hard Reload option`. Clicking this will clear the chrome cache.